# How to check a float has a normalized mantissa?

Tags: c, floating-point

When performing bit-twiddling on an float (IEEE 754), I'd like to know if the resulting value is has a normalized mantissa.

How can this be detected in C code?

Comment: Research C library: `int isnormal(real-floating x);`  (May have issue with `float` though.)

Comment: "if the resulting value is has a normalized mantissa." --> Are you looking for a quick `if (fabsf(x) >= FLT_MIN && fabsf(x) <= FLT_MAX)`?

Comment: I don't know if that's what I'm looking for since I don't know the expected behavior of non-normalized floats. From checking on isnormal: `!isfinite(x) || isnormal(x)` seems like it could do the trick though.

Comment: Hmmmm: `!isfinite(x) || isnormal(x)` looks like it would have the same result as `!isfinite(x)`

Comment: So all numbers that pass `isfinite` are by definition normalized?

Comment: @chux: If your suggestion there may be an issue with `float` is because it may be promoted to `double`, then note that the C standard specifies the test is based on the semantic type of the argument. `isnormal` is a macro, not a function call.

Comment: @ideasman42: If a floating point value is an infinite, it is not a normalized value. Infinites, NaNs and the zeros have special representations, and non of these are normalized values.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <math.h>
…
if (isnormal(x)) …
```